# UIProgressView update in background thread

Tags: objective-c, iphone, multithreading, user-interface, uiview

I have to call function calculating some thing on **MainThread** . When calculation process running, I can call UIProgressView to update UI.

When I just call update function, it's working but update **UI at last** 
I use `performSelectorInBackground` calling update function and it's **work fine**.

**Why use `performSelectorInBackground` can work**

[click here to show GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lloa8.gif)

I have seen this [What's happen if control UI by performSelectorInBackground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740561/whats-happen-if-control-ui-by-performselectorinbackground), but it not explain why `performSelectorInBackground` working.

*the sample code*
https://github.com/g78101/progressViewTest

Answer (score 0):

I find some soultion

[From the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW16):
**[myObj performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil];**
The effect of calling this method is the same as if you called the **detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:** method of **NSThread** with the current object, selector, and parameter object as parameters.

BackgroundThread just change the UI value, update UI is runnning on mainThread.

**Just NSThrad can work**

I think the reason is framework of NSThrad simpler than GCDs